# Django/PostgreSQL: How to get PostgreSQL hint using django.db.connections and the cursor() function

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql

I am using `Django` for my app backend. Due to a legacy database, I had to write custom helper functions that execute raw SQL queries.

I have this particular rollback function that I wrote and I want to be able to get the `RAISE EXCEPTION USING HINT` that was generated by the supplied query.

When the RAISE clause in the query is encountered, the HttpResponse throws error 400 which is what I wanted. I get the HINT via the console when I print out the connection cursor.

What I want now is to be able to get and store that to a variable or pass it to the HttpResponse so I can prompt it in the frontend.

**DRF API FUNCTION**

```
def post(self, request):
  try:
    text = request.data.get("text")
    query = ("""
            START TRANSACTION;
                DO $$
                  DECLARE psid INT4;

                    BEGIN
                      SELECT personid INTO psid FROM profile.systemid WHERE id=%s;

                      IF psid IS NOT NULL THEN
                        INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES (%s)
                      ELSE
                        RAISE EXCEPTION USING HINT = 'Please check that you have filled your PDS Basic Personal info first';
                      END IF;
                    END;
                $$;
    """)
    unformatted_query_result = raw_sql_insert(query, "default", (
        text
    ))
    if unformatted_query_result:
      res = raw_sql_commit_with_notices("default")
      print(res)
      return Response({
            "success": True,
            "message": "A voluntary work history has been added successfully."
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      res = raw_sql_rollback_with_notices("default")
      print(res)
      return Response({
            "success": False,
            "message": "There was a problem adding this voluntary work history."
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    return Response({
      "success": False,
      "message": "Internal System Error: " + str(e)
    }, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**HELPER FUNCTION**

```
import traceback
from django.db import connections
from collections import namedtuple

def raw_sql_commit_with_notices(connection):
   cn = connections[connection].cursor()
   try:
     cn.execute('COMMIT; END TRANSACTION;')
     return cn
   except Exception as e:
     traceback.print_exc()
     return cn

def raw_sql_rollback_with_notices(connection):
    cn = connections[connection].cursor()
    try:
        cn.execute('ROLLBACK; END TRANSACTION;')
        print("MSG: \n\n" + str(cn))
        return cn
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return cn
```

**CONSOLE RESPONSE**

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: P0001
HINT:  Please check that you have filled your PDS Basic Personal info first
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 55 at RAISE

MSG:

<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x08E66590>
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x08E66590>
HTTP POST /jobnet/api/profile/pds/voluntary_work/ 400 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:64483]
```